# DataGrid reconfigure with grid columns resulting in empty grid

Tags: extjs4.2

I am trying to use reconfigure to rearrange the columns in data grid based on user moving and rearranging the columns.
Below here I am trying to do some testing on reconfigure, but the grid becomes empty. Is this the correct way to do it?

```
var dgorder = dataGrid.getView().getGridColumns();
dataGrid.reconfigure(undefined, dgorder);
```